# Restricted airspace and lower limits

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am a new UAS pilot who will be flying agricultural fields. Naturally, my first flight location is close to a restricted airspace for military practice. I want to make sure I my flights are compliant.

R-6904A is listed as having a lower limit of 150' AGL.

If I stay under 150' AGL, then I am not technically entering this restricted airspace, correct? Would I need to contact or notify anyone about my intentions to fly if I ensure I never exceed 150' AGL?

There are additional restrictions nearby in zone R-6904B. Here, the restrictions list as starting from the surface. I will never need to enter the area controlled by this restriction, so I should be good to not notify anyone about my flights, right?

I appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: I would notify ATC anyway. I mean, there's no reason not to, right?

Comment: @MichaelHall If ATC knows you're there, they can warn you about other planes, and warn other planes about you. And [air traffic controllers would much rather be talking to you than not](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/78881/37253).

Comment: @MichaelHall ...I somehow completely missed that this was for a drone. Ignore me.

Comment: No worries!  I was kinda wondering where you were coming from...  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> R-6904A is listed as having a lower limit of 150' AGL.
>
> If I stay under 150' AGL, then I am not technically entering this
> restricted airspace, correct?

Correct.

> Would I need to contact or notify anyone about my intentions to fly if
> I ensure I never exceed 150' AGL?

No.

> There are additional restrictions nearby in zone R-6904B. Here, the
> restrictions list as starting from the surface. I will never need to
> enter the area controlled by this restriction, so I should be good to
> not notify anyone about my flights, right?

Right.

Added info -- the airspace in and near these restricted areas is Class G airspace up to 1200' AGL.  If the airspace at the altitudes where you intended to fly were other than Class G, then under [FAR 107.41](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-107) you would need to obtain prior authorization from Air Traffic Control (ATC) before flying your SUAS there (e.g. on-line authorization via the LAANC system), regardless of whether or not you were flying in a restricted area.

[Link to sectional chart showing this area](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=43.939&lon=-90.253&zoom=10&api_key=763xxE1MJHyhr48DlAP2qQ) (look near the top of the displayed area)